# PyQt - Formatting numbers in QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a question regarding how to format numbers in a DataFrame inside PyQt. I want to see numbers be displayed as 1,004,123 instead of 1004123.

I have created a `QAbstractTableModel` with `headerData`, `rowCount`, `columnCount`, and `data` functions, however I am struggling to find the procedure to format the numbers.

I believe I need to modify the QVariant input but this is where I have the problems converting to a formatted string.

```
def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        value = self.datain.values[index.row()][index.columns()]
        return QVariant(value)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of converting number to string (as suggested by Erik) you can modify numbers representation, either via reimplementing their conversion method or modifying widget's output formatting.

Comment: @mFoxRU. How else do you imagine numbers would be represented other than as strings?

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure `1,004,123` is no longer number but its string. You can achieve it by following:

```
number = 1004123
print(number)
string = "{:,}".format(number)
print(string)
```

Output:

1004123

1,004,123